# XCHANGE Apache Camel connect to Binance

Tags: apache-camel, binance

How to get data stream for using Apache Camel XCHANGE?
There is an example at [Apache Camel XCHANGE](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/xchange-component.html).
In this sample, we find the current Bitcoin market price in USDT:

```java
from("direct:ticker")
    .to("xchange:binance?service=market&method=ticker&currencyPair=BTC/USDT")
```

There is an error - it should be

```java
from("direct:ticker")
    .to("xchange:binance?service=marketdata&method=ticker&currencyPair=BTC/USDT")
```

but still have no data stream.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you're using a direct endpoint as beginning of the route. To use the route you're proposing you need to send a message to direct:ticker. If you want to fire the route automatically you can use a timer endpoint instead of direct.

The xchange endpoint is correct.